# Extend existant Elementor Widget by new $this->add_control() and add class to elementor section widget

Tags: wordpress, widget, elementor

I started to create a custom_control for the elementor section widget. I added a dropdown with a class list.

I followed this construction:
https://developers.elementor.com/docs/hooks/injecting-controls/#targeting-specific-elements

```
function inject_custom_control( $element, $section_id, $args ) {

    if ( 'section' === $element->get_name() && 'section_background' === $section_id ) {

        $element->start_controls_section(
            'custom_section',
            [
                'tab' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TAB_STYLE,
                'label' => esc_html__( 'Kraiburg Einstellungen', 'textdomain' ),
            ]
        );

        $element->add_control(
            'bg_color',
            [
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SELECT,
                'label' => esc_html__( 'BG Color', 'textdomain' ),
                'options' => [
                    'white' => esc_html__( 'white', 'textdomain' ),
                    'kb-blue' => esc_html__( 'blue', 'textdomain' ),
                    'kb-light-blue' => esc_html__( 'light-blue', 'textdomain' ),
                    'kb-yellow' => esc_html__( 'yellow', 'textdomain' ),
                    'kb-dark-blue' => esc_html__( 'dark-blue', 'textdomain' ),
                ],
                'default' => 'white',
            ]
        );

        $element->end_controls_section();

    }

}
add_action( 'elementor/element/before_section_start', 'inject_custom_control', 10, 3 );
```

So far so good.

The dropdown appears in my elementor editor. But how i can edit the HTML output of the elementor section widget? I want to add the class name.

Answer (score 1):

It will be a little late reply but I do use;

```
    $element->add_control(
    'bg_color',
    [
        'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SELECT,
        'label' => esc_html__( 'BG Color', 'textdomain' ),
        'options' => [
            'white' => esc_html__( 'white', 'textdomain' ),
            'kb-blue' => esc_html__( 'blue', 'textdomain' ),
            'kb-light-blue' => esc_html__( 'light-blue', 'textdomain' ),
            'kb-yellow' => esc_html__( 'yellow', 'textdomain' ),
            'kb-dark-blue' => esc_html__( 'dark-blue', 'textdomain' ),
        ],
        'default' => 'white',
        'prefix_class' => '',
    ]
);
```

as you can see only added prefix_class, now you section will have selected value with other CSS class names like below;

```
class="elementor-section elementor-top-section elementor-element elementor-element-bc33e25 kb-yellow elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default"
```

Works with Elementor 3.13.4 free version, hope it helps.